# explode pipe delimiter string into array with name and value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, explode

I'm trying to separate a string which has multiple values separated by ; with each value and key separated by |. I ideally want this to end up looking like this:

```
$array = array(
   array( "qty" => "2", "code" => "YQTWEY33" ),
   array( "qty" => "1", "code" => "YQTWEY53" )
)
```

I have the string in a variable called $str and I'm using the explode function to separate out the different values. However, i'm not really sure where to go from here. Can anyone help please?

```
$str = "qty: 2 | code: YQTWEY33; qty: 1 | code: YQTWEY53";

$topics = array();
foreach (explode(';', $str) as $topic) {
    list($name, $items) = explode('|', $topic);
    $topics[$name] = explode(':', $items);
    print_r($topics);
}
```

Comment: Note if you use `preg_split('/\s*;\s*/', $str)` instead of `explode(';', $str)` then your strings will be automatically trimmed of whitespace and you won't have to do it manually later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "qty: 2 | code: YQTWEY33; qty: 1 | code: YQTWEY53";

$topics = array();
foreach (explode(';', $str) as $index=> $topic) {
    foreach(explode('|', $topic ) as $item ) {
        list($key, $value) = explode(':', $item);
        $topics[$index][trim($key)] = trim($value);
    }
}
print_r($topics);
```